# SSL Handshake error when using proxy with requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, http-proxy

```
url = "https://google.com"
session = requests.session()
proxy = {
        "http": "http://REDACTED:12345",
        "https": "https://REDACTED:12345"
    }
r = session.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': get_random_agent()}, proxies=proxy)
print(r.status_code)
```

I am trying to make a `get` request with a proxy via the `requests` library.  I have the above code snippet to demonstrate what I am trying to do.  This snippet is working on one PC I have.  However, I just recently  got a new PC and when trying to execute the same code snippet on my new PC, I get this error -

```
TimeoutError: _ssl.c:980: The handshake operation timed out
```

If I remove `proxies=proxy` it works fine on my new PC.  I have openssl 1.1.1 installed and python 3.10.